# NODATA on MapServer

Tags: dem, mapserver, nodata, wcs

I am trying to generate a DEM mosaic to publish via a WCS using MapServer. Unfortunately I can not remove the NODATA. In MapServer's own tutorials and discussion groups suggest PROCESSING "NODATA = 0", but it does not work.

Has anyone here ever had such a problem, if so, did you solve it?

Comment: Please explain what you want to do and include links to your sources. Is your use case like this http://geoexamples.blogspot.fi/2013/11/fast-tip-drawing-raster-no-data-values.html?

Comment: It seems to me that the `PROCESSING "NODATA = 0"` directive might just be saying that the nodata value (to ignore) is 0.  Is 0 your nodata value?

Answer (score 0):

For WCS 2.0 you can set this in the METADATA of a LAYER for specific format options:

```
METADATA
    # this metadata item is in the format wcs_outputformat_{OUTPUTFORMAT}_creationoption_{FORMATOPTION}     
    "wcs_outputformat_GEOTIFF_INT16_creationoption_nullvalue" "0" # WCS 2.0 only
END
```

For WCS 1.0 the following METADATA option should be used:

```
METADATA
    "wcs_rangeset_nullvalue" "0"
END
```

There is a test repository and details at https://github.com/geographika/wcs-test with more details and options.